# Clojure macro to read a file

Tags: macros, clojure

I want to create a Clojure macro that can read a file, when the file is read successfully the stream should be closed.

```
(import '(java.io FileReader File))

(defmacro read([x y]
`(let ~x 
  (try ~y 
   (. x close)
    (catch Exception e# e#)))))
```

Called like this,

```
(read [stream (java.io.FileReader (java.io.File "somefile.txt"))] (. stream read)))
```

Results in this error

```
java.lang.Exception: No such var: user/x (NO_SOURCE_FILE:8)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Can you give more information regarding the error message that you're getting? Is it a runtime error or compile time?

Comment: @PieterBreed java.lang.Exception: No such var: user/x (NO_SOURCE_FILE:8)

Comment: On the 4th line of your macro, "x" is not unquoted. There is still a lot wrong with this...

Comment: Yes, and if I quote "~x" this exception is thrown <IllegalArgumentException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: close for class clojure.lang.PersistentVector>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aren't you looking for `with-open`, unless there is some reason that you want to explicitly use a macro?

```
(defn read [file-name]
  (with-open [reader (BufferedReader. (FileReader. file-name))]
    (doseq [line (line-seq reader)] (println line))))
```

According to the [ClojureDocs page](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-open), it ensures that the reader is closed at the end of the form.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Is it performing a similar function to with-open? Or do you want to do something drastically different? If it's going to be the same, it might be worthwhile to read the source, the ClojureDocs page I've linked to contains the source for the function if you want to read it...

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, and if I quote "~x" this exception is thrown

```
<IllegalArgumentException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: close for class clojure.lang.PersistentVector>
```

This is because `'~x"` now refers to `[stream (FileReader. (File. "somefile.txt"))]`.  The error you are getting makes sense.  The macro spits out code which tries to call `close()` on the above vector.  You could experiment with using `(first ~x)`.

Note that this macro is extremely general, and does not significantly reduce the amount of code the user has to write.

You could try something along these lines (this probably does not work)

```
(import '(java.io FileReader File))

(defmacro read([fname]
`(try
   (let [stream# (FileReader. (File. ~fname))
         rtnval (. stream# read)]
     (do 
       (. stream# close)
       rtnval))
   (catch Exception e# e#)))
```

But I'm only like 50% sure my answer makes any sense.